# Determine if ranks of a group are different

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric

I have some data that the response variable is color of potato chip.  It has a large positive skew.  There are 7 potato varieties and 8 different locations in this study.  I want to rank the potato varieties from lightest color to darkest color based on location and do a test to see if their are differences in the ranks between locations, like do the varieties have the same rank in every location or do they change?  I don't know what test to do....